# Drawing Line on Bing maps disappears

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am drawing a line on the bing maps in my app with the polyline code. But when i zoom
into the map, the polyline disappears. Do you know what i am doing wrong?
thank you very much

the code looks like this:

```
MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
polyline.Stroke = stroke;
polyline.StrokeThickness = strokeThinkness;
polyline.Opacity = opacity;
polyline.Locations = locationsList;
MyMap.Children.Add(polyline);
```

Comment: Not a clue, until you share your code that you used to do it.